# Decreasing family of path connected open sets containing two points has a common path.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I was trying to use van Kampen theorem on fundamental groupoids to prove the van Kampen theorem on fundamental groups. I got stuck at the following technicality.

> Let $\{U_i\}$ be a decreasing family of path connected open sets, such that $U_i\ni x,y$ and $x\ne y$. Then is it true that there is a path $x\to y$ that is contained in all $U_i$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the open unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the origin removed. Then consider the points $x=(1/2,0)$ and $y=(-1/2,0)$. Choose an infinite decreasing collection of open sets that shrink to smaller and smaller neighborhoods around $x$ and $y$, and are connected by a thin open horizontal band centered around the $x$-axis. The band becomes thinner and thinner as $i$ increases. Then the infinite intersection of these open sets will be a horizontal segment from $x$ to $y$ with the origin removed, and there will be no path from $x$ to $y$ in the intersection. Thus there is no one path from $x$ to $y$ contained in all the $U_i$. However all the $U_i$ are path connected and contain $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Why won't the intersection in your exampe contain the origin?

Comment: Because it was excluded in the beginning. Removing the origin from the $U_i$ doesn't change their path-connectedness, but it does for the infinite intersection.